# If a graph G has distinct edge costs > 0 (i.e. no two edge costs are the same), is every minimum-bottleneck tree of G also a minimum-spanning tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

My initial answer is yes with a proof by contradiction.

*"Suppose there is a minimum-bottleneck tree T1 of G and a minimum spanning tree T2 of G such that T1 is not equal to T2. This means the total weight of edges of T1 is greater than the weight of edges of T2. Since all edge costs are distinct, this means the bottleneck edge value of T1 must be greater than that of T2 . However if this is true then that means T2 has a bottleneck smaller than that of T1 , meaning T1 is not an MBST, which is a contradiction. QED.*

I know if the edge costs are not distinct then the answer would be no, an MBST is not necessarily a MST but if the edge costs are distinct I believe that changes things.

Comment: You can add a very heavy edge and a new vertex to *any* two spanning trees to get two distinct MBSTs, but there is only one MST.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a logical leap in concluding, "*Since all edge costs are distinct, this means the bottleneck edge value of T1 must be greater than that of T2*" from "*This means the total weight of edges of T1 is greater than the weight of edges of T2.*"

The total weight is a sum.  One sum can be bigger than another even though both have the same largest term.  Whether or not the numbers involved are distinct is irrelevant.

Look for a small counter-example with 4 vertices and 4 edges.